# Display data that hasnt been inputted into mysql within the past 24 hours

Tags: mysql

outputting mysql values that haven't been entered into the database in more than 24 hours.

I have tried to join a secondary table and compare date inputs where the date is larger than 1 day but when i run the query it doesn't seem to filter out the data that has been entered in the previous 24 hours.

```
SELECT t1.value,t1.date,t1.time
FROM filter t1 LEFT JOIN filter t2
ON (t1.value= t2.value AND concat(t1.date,' ',t1.time) < 
concat(t2.date,t2.time)) WHERE t2.date > curdate() - interval 1 day;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d41ea/2

my ideal outcome is to have the below example where date is 06/01/19

```
value        date
  1        01/01/19 
  1        05/01/19 
  2        05/01/19 
  2        06/01/19 
  3        03/01/19 
  3        04/01/19 
  4        05/01/19 
  4        06/01/19
```

select value(number) not present in database in the past day ( 05/01/19 and 06/01/19) display result

numbers present in past day 1.2.4 dont display in results

numbers not present in the past day 3 display in results

query such as

```
select value,date from filter where date < curdate() - interval 1 day but not > curdate() - interval 1 day
```

Comment: this is 100% unclear.

Comment: why is it unclear? im trying to display data from mysql that isnt present in the database in the previous 24 hours

Comment: Is unclear what you are asking, you example, this post. Everything here is unclear. Please take some times and think about a better way to expose what you are looking at.

Comment: Also your english is unclear

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` ?

Comment: By the way, naming fields `value`, `date`, `time` is a very bad idea. They are reserved MySQL keywords.

Comment: @Cid value,date,time are only inputted here and sql fiddle the columns are named different in my database

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain the desired data (e.g. for 06/01/19)

Answer (score 0):

In this example I get all the values that are expected to have transacted in the last 24 hours  then left join to see if they have,

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
  value VARCHAR(45),
  date DATE,
  time TIME

);
INSERT INTO t (value,date,time) 
VALUES ('1','2019-01-10','14:30:00'),
('1','2019-01-10','14:30:00'),
('1','2019-01-13','14:31:00'),
('1','2019-01-14','14:32:00'),
('2','2019-01-10','14:30:00'),
('2','2019-01-13','14:31:00'),
('2','2019-01-14','14:32:00'),
('3','2019-01-10','14:30:00'),
('3','2019-01-13','14:31:00'),
('3','2019-01-14','14:32:00'),
('4','2019-01-10','14:30:00'),
('4','2019-01-13','14:31:00'),
('4','2019-01-14','14:32:00'),
('5','2019-01-01','14:00:00');


select s.value,s.dt,t.dt
from
(
select distinct value,last24hr.dt
from t
cross join (select date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) dt) last24hr
) s
left join
(select value,cast(concat(date,' ',time) as datetime) dt from t) t
on s.value = t.value and s.dt <= t.dt
where t.dt is null;

+-------+---------------------+------+
| value | dt                  | dt   |
+-------+---------------------+------+
| 5     | 2019-01-13 12:08:23 | NULL |
+-------+---------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

None of your sample fail of course so I added 5 which will probably not be found by the time you test this(if you do)